# Javascript calling other object method

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have these two objects: A and B. I want to call A.something from B, but is not working...

```
A = function()
{
  function something()
  {
     //do something
  }
}

B = function()
{
  A.something();
}
```

this throws "typeError, A.something(); is not a function"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code attempts to use `A` as an object when it is a function. You would need to invoke the function `A()`, but then its `something` method would *still* not be available (because it is not exposed).

If you want `A` to be an object, you could use an object literal like this:

```
A = {
  something: function()
  {
     //do something
  }
}

B = function()
{
  A.something();
}
```

Or for a more *classical* looking approach you could use `new`:

```
function A()
{
  this.something()
  {
     //do something
  }
}

B = function()
{
  var a = new A();
  a.something();
}
```

There are more ways as well.  You can use `Object.create` or use a more *functional* approach by returning an object inside the `A` function.

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare `A` as a function itself, declare it as an object:

```
A = {}
```

Then inside place `something` as your function:

```
A = {
    something: function() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

You will now be able to call `A.something()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, to create an object in javascript you have to define your class `A` like this (easy approach, not using prototyping):

```
A = function()
{ 
  return {
    something = function()
    {
       //do something
    }
  }
}
```

Then create your object by calling `var object = A()`.

So your code should look like this in the end:

```
A = function()
{ 
  return {
    something = function()
    {
       //do something
    }
  }
}

B = function()
{
  var aObject = A();
  aObject.something();
}
```

Comment: How about the *other* ways to create an object?  `new` or `Object.create` come to mind...

Comment: Well, that would be far to much to cover in this post. I will not write a tutorial on how to do object oriented coding in js

Comment: I was referring to the `you have to` part of the first sentence.